# Java: Calling a method in another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to get my first class to run a method `ShutDownServer` in my second class. What do I need to change for the method to be called?

My First Class (I've removed all extra code):

```
//imports the other class
package examples;
import examples.Class2;

//Below line has error: The method ShutDownServer() is undefined for the type Class2
Class2.shutDownServer();
```

My Second class:

```
package examples;

public class Class2 {
    public void shutDownServer() {
        System.out.println("It Works?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Build` compile? I notice a missing brace.

Comment: Do you have 2 `Build` classes with the same name?

Comment: Remember to start method name with lowercase!

Comment: The Build class seems to be missing a package declaration?

Comment: It had the package declaration already, I just missed copying it here... (fixed now)

Comment: do you know what an instance is?

Answer (score 2):

Either make the shutDownServer method static...

```
public static void shutDownServer() {
```

Or, simply instantiate a Class2 object and call the method...

```
Class2 server = new Class2();
server.shutDownServer();
```

The method signature for shutDownServer will depend on the nature of the design choices you make with your application.

And you don't need to have that import for examples.Class2, given that the calling object is in that package already: `package examples;`